# Batch file ECHO not working after PUSHD command

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, command

I have a .bat (batch) file with the following line, the last line echo isn't run.

```
set outputfile=C:\DeployLog-label-test.txt
echo ----- Start File 1 of 1 ----- >> %outputfile%
pushd C:\src&ant -Dinifile=C:\repo\IR.ini -Dfilelist="label.xml" >> %outputfile% 2>&1&popd
echo ----- End File 1 of 1 ----- >> %outputfile%
```

Is it because of pushd command?
Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, in this case the "problem" is that `ant` is a batch file, and if from inside a batch file (your batch file) you call another batch file, execution flow is transfered to the called batch and it does not return to the caller. UNLESS the call of the second batch file is done with `call` command. So, your code should be

```
pushd C:\src&call ant -Dinifile=C:\repo\IR.ini -Dfilelist="label.xml" >> %outputfile% 2>&1&popd
```

Comment: Thanks. Now the last line is writing into the log file, however, it doesn't write to the console! Any idea?

Comment: @Chybie: you are sending (redirection `>>`) the output of the first echo, the execution of ant and the second echo to the output file. If output is send to log file, it will not go to the console. If you need the output on both, use something like `tee` (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11239924/2861476) for a good list of options).